# custom element with preset-typescript in legacy (IE, IOS < 10.3)

Tags: typescript, web-component, custom-element

I'm using the Custom Element for my project. 
I thought I finished the project without a hitch, but some browsers have a problem.
I don't think he understood the Custom Element environment.

The problem is, the script does not work in browsers less than version 10.3 or in ie.

From what I looked for today, maybe... I don't think it's possible to solve this without a modern browser. Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Yes, Custom Elements are only supported in modern Browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elementsv1 For older browsers there are Polyfills: https://www.webcomponents.org/polyfills